# How can I pause music in task switcher and lock screen?

Tags: ios

I need to play music from url in background on ios. I've tried `MPMoviePlayerController` and `AVPlayer`, which can successfully play music in background.

But I can't stop music from the "Pause" button in task switcher and lock screen. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in following answers:

For pausing music from task switcher:
[iOS MPMoviePlayerController playing audio in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540726/ios-mpmovieplayercontroller-playing-audio-in-background)

For displaying info, including album picture, see [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)